# ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia returns URIs only by creation date order

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, photo-picker

In Jetpack Compose the new Photo Picker form Android 13 returns URIs ordered by creation date instead of the order you selected pictures.

Im using the `ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia` for picking multiple picture and I was expecting it to return me a list of URIs sorted by the order I selected the pictures. But it seems like it's not supported that way and you can't really tweak it. How can I achive the desired behaviour without to have to implement my own picker?

Comment: Is there any specific need for having the URIs as per user selection? because I believe you would already have all the photos

Comment: Well, I mean, that's a pretty common behaviour that when you, for example, attach photos to your message - they attach in the order you selected them

Comment: @WillShepard did you found something about the issue? I have the same issue and would get the good order